# react. Can't pass object into component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one render function I create 1-3 components BigText

```
return (<div>{ d.sql[0] !== null ? <BigText content={d.sql[0]}>SQL</BigText> : <span>&nbsp;</span> }
    { d.event[0] !== null ? <BigText content={d.event[0]}>Event</BigText> : <span>&nbsp;</span>}
    { d.stacktrace[0] !== null ? <BigText content={d.stacktrace[0]}>Trace</BigText> : <span>&nbsp;</span>}</div>)
```

d is a real object `Object {sql: Array[1], stacktrace: Array[1], event: Array[1]}`. This code seems correct.

But the object passed as content is not present in the BigText component render.

```
class BigText extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggleViewer = this.toggleViewer.bind(this);
        console.log(this);
    }

    toggleViewer() {
        console.log(this);
        this.props.viewerToggle(this.props.content);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this);
        return (<FlatButton primary={true} onTouchTap={this.toggleViewer}>{this.props.children}</FlatButton>)
    }
}

BigText.propTypes = {
    class: React.PropTypes.string,
    content: React.PropTypes.any.isRequered
}
```

Logged this object. As you see below props.content is null when component has been called to render, it is also null when constructor has been called:

```
BigText
  props 
    children: "SQL"
    content: null
    isViewerOpened: false
    viewerToggle: function ()
    __proto__: Object
  context: Object 
  refs: Object
  updater: Object
  ...
```

Where to dig to solve this issue?

Comment: The only time you use `this.props.content` is when it's passed as an argument to the function `this.props.viewerToggle`. But you haven't defined `this.props.viewerToggle` anywhere.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh But `this.props.content` is null when render called (console.log(this) in render() show it). Once I get it in render() I write more code to pass data to the toggleViewer()